# Play video first, then load poster of last video frame using BigVideo.js

Tags: jquery, video

(Novice Programmer here)

I'm using BigVideo.js to play a video in the background of a landing page, and I'm trying to get it to end on the last frame, how do I set the poster image to be the video's last frame?  Would this be a setting to change in bigvideo.js or video.js?

```
 $(function() {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            if (Modernizr.touch) {
                BV.show('images/bg.png');
            } else {
                BV.show('vids/4.mov', {ambient:false});
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I need to switch to poster at the end of the video.